# .htaccess Hide php param keys from url but dont change physical path

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am looking for a solution to hide param keys from my url

for example /page1.php?city=Lahore

I want it to rewrite as /page1/Lahore

but the most important thing is Lahore is not a directory exist on server I want it to point to same file page1.php just rewrite url externally

thanks

Comment: I have this solution doing the job
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:page1\.php)?\?city=([^\s&]+) [NC]

#RewriteRule ^ /page1.php/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

but it try to load directory Lahore that not actually exist

Answer (score 1):

create an .htaccess file from the root and paste this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1/(.*)? /page1.php?city=$1 [L]
```

or you could also put it in your website apache conf file.

Comment: but this will be specific on "page1" it's not generic..
if you have "page1", "page2" ..etc...

You could write ^page(\d)+/(.*)? /page$1.php?city=$2 [L]

Comment: well the code you just shared is not working, 
currently the code is working for me is

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:page1\.php)?\?city=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /m/en/page1.php/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

Comment: But now the problem is that my js files are not loading 
as the path is showing now adding /m/en/page1.php/js/myscript.js 
that should need to be /m/en/js/myscript.js

Answer (score 0):

try this code 
for .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectfoldername/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^page1/(.+?)/?$ /projectfoldername/page1.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

page1.php code will be

```
<?php 
echo $_REQUEST['key'];  
?>
```

then call
http://localhost/projectfoldername/page1/1947

output will be :1947